Spanish legal TV series
Some 12-15 years ago I watched on TV a Spanish series about a team of an investigating judge, a lawyer (two males) and their two assistants (female). The judge, if I'm not mistaken, was called Cosmo. The title (as translated in my language) was something like "Public defence - 10 years later".
Not sure how helpful this will be, but the opening credits used the 3rd movement from Telemann's Trumpet Concerto in F minor.
Does anyone remember the show I'm talking about?

The use in the credits doesn't seem to be listed on IMDb... which isn't that unusual for a foreign TV series but you might look it over to see if I missed it.

I think it's the TVE show Turno de oficio: Diez años después from 1996, the sequel to Turno de oficio from 1986. I think it because the show's title means something like "Public defence: 10 years later", there's a main character called Cosme and its intro is accompanied by the 3rd movement from Telemann's Trumpet Concerto in F minor. You pretty much solved the question yourself. ;)




Walt, you made my day! Thank you! I've been searching for this show's name for years.
